# Generating a vector with with a random uniform direction and a Gaussian-distributed magnitude

Tags: python, vector, distribution

I want to add 2D Gaussian noise to each (x,y) point of a list that I have.

That is why I want to create a noise vector with a random uniform direction over [0, 2pi) and a Gaussian-distributed magnitude with N(0, \sigma^2).

How can I generate a vector in Python only specifying the direction and its magnitude?

Comment: Why not simply adding Gaussian noise to each coordinate (x, y) separately?

Comment: @IgorF.Maybe I did not express myself well enough. I want to generate a noise vector for each (x,y) coordinate. Separately. Thiis means every point has its own noise vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is not hard to do

```
n = 100
sigma = 1.0

phi = 2.0 * np.pi * np.random.random(n)
r   = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=sigma, size=n)

x   = r*np.cos(phi)
y   = r*np.sin(phi)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate two vectors, one for the magnitude and another for the phase. Then you use both to get what you want.

```py
import numpy as np
import math

sigma_squred = 0.01  # Change to whatever value you want
num_elements = 10    # Size of the vector you want

magnitude = math.sqrt(sigma_squred) * np.random.randn(num_elements)
phase = 2 * np.pi * np.random.random_sample(num_elements)

# This will give you a vector with a Gaussian magnitude and a random phase between 0 and 2PI
noise = magnitude * np.exp(1j*phase)
```

I find it easier to work with a single vector of complex numbers, but since you have individual x and y values, you can get a `noise_x` and a `noise_y` vector with

```py
noise_x = noise.real
noise_y = noise.imag
```

**Note**: I'm assuming you can use the numpy library, which make things much easier. If that is not the case you will need a loop to generate each element. To generate a single sample for magnitude you can use `random.gauss(0, sigma)`, while `2*math.pi*random.random()` can be used to generate a sample for the phase. Then you do the same as before to get a complex number from where you can get the real and the imaginary parts.

Comment: Mixing math and numpy is not a good idea. Better stick to NumPy

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux The reason why I mix them is performance. We can check with IPython `%timeit` magic command. In my machine  `np.sqrt(15)` took 735ns with std of 5.49. On the other hand, `math.sqrt(15)` took 73.5ns with std of 1.19ns.

```python
In [1]: %timeit np.sqrt(15)                                                           
735 ns ± 5.49 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit math.sqrt(15)                                                         
73.5 ns ± 1.19 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```